# Bulk update product price and stock

Tags: magento2, product, php, magento2.3

In the Catalog > Products page you can go to Actions > Update Attributes at the top left and then bulk update product stock/quantity/etc.

How can I do this using the Magento PHP PDO but in bulk like this instead of one by one?

i.e. I already have a solution for one by one;

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->create('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

    $outOfStockProducts = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 9);
    $inStockProducts = array(2, 6, 7, 8, 10);

    //For out of stock products
    foreach($outOfStockProducts as $k=>$id){
        $product = $productRepository->getById($id);
        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty(0);
        $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
    }

    //For 100 stock products
    foreach($inStockProducts as $k=>$id){
        $product = $productRepository->getById($id);
        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty(100);
        $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
    }
```

How can I do this in bulk as the Magento feature does it instead of one by one like the example?
The reason being is that the bulk operation completes almost instantaneously, compared to the one by one method which may take hours to complete.

Comment: Just try Magmi,

Comment: Is that importer? I need for updating stock on a regular basis

Comment: You can also update via magmi.